# Magnetic Induction - How would different coil configurations affect the outcome?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

This is a branch question (from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110087/what-are-the-variables-at-play-during-magnetic-induction)) related to magnetic induction:

These deal with how different configurations of coiled layers might affect the outcome:

- If one were to bundle multiple layers of coiling to up the coils, would it be more effective to have each layer connected in parallel and running in the same direction? (example - 2 ins and 2 outs)
- If one were to coil 'loosely' such that the wire is wrapping around the coil at a 45 degree angle - would it generate less induction than the same number of coils tighter coiled at nearly a 90 degree angle (pretty sure this is a yes - but wondering if there is any silver lining in terms of resistance - perhaps with a deluge of parallel-connected layers))?
- In the event that two or more layers are connected in parallel - would the energy created across each layer likely be significantly less? In the event of (say) five layers of coiling connecting, each with differing currents (or voltages), how might the resultant current be combined once reunited (presuming a similar wire is receiving the energy)?

I am keenly interested in the variables at play being defined - as well as any information on how such might play out. Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

- Two coils (around the same core) with the same number of turns, connected in parallel, will work and have less resistance. But one can reach the same objective using a thicker wire. Two coils (around the same core) with different numbers of turns, connected in parallel, are effectively a short circuit for a coil with a magnetic core, and anyway not a good thing as it grossly reduces inductance.
- Only magnetic flux captured by the wire does matter, not angles. If one neglects the magnetic field outside the core, then the number of turns around the core is the only relevant thing. There are, in principle, some magnetic fields outside the core. Although these effects depend on geometry of the coil, there is little difference whether the wire runs at 90° to the axis of the core or at 45° (except in the latter case it will be $\sqrt2$ times longer for the same number of turns).
- Unintelligible for me.

Note that “energy created across… layer” is definitely a crackpot language. First, the energy is *transferred*, not created. Second, considerations of the energy conservation would only obfuscate this concrete model, where the magnetic field and its flux are important quantity, not energy.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response. Relating to the third point - I am of the assumption that multiple coils wrapped at different distances from the core (because they are on top of each other) would each be induced to different degrees. Assuming the voltage is, say, 10 Volts and the Amps generated in 3 layers of coils is 3 Amps, 2 Amps and 1 Amp respectively, what might one expect when the three coils combine at the out-point?

Comment: @Avestron: you assume that a coil that is farther from the core is “less powerful”. It is not exactly so, although a farther coil might have greater resistance for the same number of turns.

You also ask about amperes. One can’t answer you question without a knowledge how the transformer is powered.

Comment: Well thank you for your insights in any case :) I am a layperson myself and so found your feedback useful in expanding my limited and unreliable understanding.